# Aurelia: validating form with reusable validatable custom element

Tags: aurelia

**Short question:** How can I validate a parent form when the validation is part of child custom elements?

**Long version:**

I built a reusable custom element which includes validation which is working like I expect it to do:

validated-input.html:

```
<template>
<div class="form-group" validate.bind="validation">
    <label></label>
    <input type="text" value.bind="wert" class="form-control" />
</div>
</template>
```

validated-input.js:

```
import { bindable, inject } from 'aurelia-framework';
import { Validation } from 'aurelia-validation';

@inject(Validation)
export class ValidatedInputCustomElement {
    @bindable wert;

    constructor(validation) {
        this.validation = validation.on(this)
        .ensure('wert')
            .isNotEmpty()
            .isGreaterThan(0);
    }
}
```

I will have some forms that will use this custom element more than once in the same view (can be up to 8 or 12 times or even more). A very simplified example could look like this:

```
<template>
  <require from="validated-input"></require>
  <form submit.delegate="submit()">
    <validated-input wert.two-way="val1"></validated-input>
    <validated-input wert.two-way="val2"></validated-input>
    <validated-input wert.two-way="val3"></validated-input>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">save</button>
  </form>
</template>
```

In the corresponding viewmodel file I would like to ensure that the data can only be submitted if everything is valid. I would like to do something like

```
this.validation.validate()
    .then(() => ...)
    .catch(() => ...);
```

but I don't understand yet how (or if) I can pull the overall validation into the parent view.

What I came up with up to now is referencing the viewmodel of my validated-input like this:

```
<validated-input wert.two-way="val1" view-model.ref="vi1"></validated-input>
```

and then to check it in the parent like this:

```
this.vi1.validation.validate()
    .then(() => ...)
    .catch(() => ...);
```

but this would make me need to call it 8/12/... times.

And I will probably have some additional validation included in the form.

Here is a plunkr with an example:
https://plnkr.co/edit/v3h47GAJw62mlhz8DeLf?p=info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define an array of validation objects (as Fabio Luz wrote) at the form level and then register the custom element validations in this array. The validation will be started on the form submit.

The form code looks like:

```
validationArray = [];

validate() {
    var validationResultsArray = [];

    // start the validation here
    this.validationArray.forEach(v => validationResultsArray.push(v.validate()));

    Promise.all(validationResultsArray)
        .then(() => this.resulttext = "validated")
        .catch(() => this.resulttext = "not validated");
}
```

`validated-input.js` gets a new function to register the validation

```
bind(context) {
    context.validationArray.push(this.validation);
}
```

The plunker example is here https://plnkr.co/edit/X5IpbwCBwDeNxxpn55GZ?p=preview

Comment: This is a nice approach. It reduces the amount of code needed significantly.
But the custom element has to know about the 'validationArray' property of the parent, I will probably accept that, but if anyone has a solution without this coupling I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

> but this would make me need to call it 8/12/... times.
>
> And I will probably have some additional validation included in the form.

These lines are very important to me. In my opinion (considering that you do not want to call 8/12 times, and you also need an additional validation), you should validate the entire form, instead of each element. In that case, you could inject the validation in the root component (or the component that owns the form), like this:

```
import { Validation } from 'aurelia-validation';
import { bindable, inject } from 'aurelia-framework';

@inject(Validation)
export class App {
  val1 = 0;
  val2 = 1;
  val3 = 2;
  
  resulttext = "";
  
  constructor(validation) {
    this.validation = validation.on(this)
      .ensure('val1')
        .isNotEmpty()
        .isGreaterThan(0)
      .ensure('val2')
        .isNotEmpty()
        .isGreaterThan(0)
      .ensure('val3')
        .isNotEmpty()
        .isGreaterThan(0);
     //some additional validation here
  }
  
  validate() {
    this.validation.validate()
        .then(() => this.resulttext = "valid")
        .catch(() => this.resulttext = "not valid");
  }
}
```

View:

```
<template>
  <require from="validated-input"></require>
  <form submit.delegate="validate()" validation.bind="validation">
    <validated-input wert.two-way="val1"></validated-input>
    <validated-input wert.two-way="val2"></validated-input>
    <validated-input wert.two-way="val3"></validated-input>
    
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">validate</button>
  </form>
  <div>${resulttext}</div>
</template>
```

Now, you can re-use the `validated-input` component in other places. And of course, you probably have to rename it, because the name `validated-input` does not make sense in this case.

Here is the plunker example https://plnkr.co/edit/gd9S2y?p=preview

---

Another approach would be pushing all the validation objects into an array and then calling a function to validate all validations objects, but that sounds strange to me.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I didn't want to validate this way, because now I would need to write 

`ensure('val1')
        .isNotEmpty()
        .isGreaterThan(0)`

8 or 12 or ... times, and I need the validations rule to be customized or changed easily. They will be different for another client and that would mean a lot of code to change... That's why I'm trying to incorporate the validation (and formatting/globalization of numbers, etc.) in the custom element.