# aurelia - Custom Element validation

Tags: validation, aurelia, custom-element

I have a custom element (a partial URL) called `@customElement('partialurl')`

**partialurl.js**

```
get isValid(){
    if (this.element === undefined || this.element === null){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        const partialUrl = new RegExp('^\/[a-z0-9]+([-\/](?:[a-z0-9]+))*(\.(?:jpeg|jpg|gif|png|htm|html|asp|xml|txt|pdf))?$');
        if (partialUrl.test(this.element)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

My question is how do I reference the 'isValid'?

For example - this file references the custom element

**html**

```
<partialurl disabled.bind="readonly" value.bind="baseContent.LinkDestination" />
```

**js**

```
bind(){
    return this.dataContext.getContent(this.id)
        .then(baseContent => {
            this.baseContent = baseContent;
             this.validator = this.validation.on(this)  
              .ensure('baseContent.LinkDestination').isValidFromCustomElement();
        }); }
```

I know the above doesn't work, I am new to Aurelia and still finding my feet with it.

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35624771/aurelia-validating-form-with-reusable-validatable-custom-element ?

Comment: @lliaj yes I had seen this, I came to the same conclusion as the user asking the question - The CE has to know about the 'validationArray', I was hoping there was an easier way.